# WebView with scrolling bar at the top

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I have to create an app which UI is quite similar to Chrome. In other words, I have to create a WebView, and a bar at top of it, which:

- disappears as user scrolls the page down (the bar scrolls with the page),
- reappears when user scrolls the page up,
- when the user scrolls the page so only half of the bar is visible, then it just disappear.

The important (probably) thing is that I cannot modify the HTML displayed. What I've already figured out is that I should create my own class that extends the WebView and override the `onScrollChanged()` in it. This is what I managed to write:

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);

    if (flag) {
        flag = false;
        return;
    }
    View bar = getRootView().findViewById(R.id.bar);
    if (bar != null) {
        int difft = oldt - t;
        float oldY = bar.getTranslationY();
        float newY = Math.max(-bar.getHeight(), Math.min(0, bar.getTranslationY() + difft));
        bar.setTranslationY(newY);
        View layout = getRootView().findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layout.setTranslationY(bar.getHeight() + newY);

        flag = true;
        if ((int) (newY - oldY) != 0) {
            scrollBy(0, difft);
        }
    }
}
```

(layout is the container the WebView is in, and bar is the top bar. I placed both Views in RelativeLayout)

And well, it almost works. Almost, because it causes some flickering, and I don't know what's the problem. Also, it does not solve problem #3 (and I don't actually know how to solve it by the simpliest way, with some sort of animation, like in Chrome - a smooth move to the up).

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @joluet: well, not actually. At some point it became useless to me, so I haven't even tried to go any further, but I'll still be happy if someone provides working solution.